# How to build a C code for avr atmega32 microcontroller to measure power using ZMPT101B voltage sensor and SCT013 current sensor?

Tags: c, microcontroller, atmega32

I'm constructing a device to measure power and display in a 16x2 LCD in a given power source. I'm using the above mentioned sensors to read current and voltage through ADC in ATMega32. Voltage sensor is connected to PA0 and current sensor to PA1.

I did a calibration and found a relationship between bit value and actual current/voltage.
From these actual values, my aim is to do a discrete Fourier transformation as the power gets alternate with the time if I only display the actual values.
I have constructed a C code as follows:

```
#define F_CPU 8000000UL     // CPU Frequency to 8MHz
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LCD_Dir  DDRC
#define LCD_Port PORTC
#define RS       PC0
#define EN       PC1

#define VOLTAGE_SENSOR_CHANNEL 0
#define CURRENT_SENSOR_CHANNEL 1
#define N 256  // Number of data points 

// Sampled voltage and current data 
double voltage_data[N];
double current_data[N];
double power_data[N];

// Function to perform DFT on a single frequency component
void dft(double data[], int n, double* result_real, double* result_imag, double frequency) {
    *result_real = 0;
    *result_imag = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        double angle = 2.0 * M_PI * frequency * k / n;
        *result_real += data[k] * cos(angle);
        *result_imag -= data[k] * sin(angle); // Use subtraction here for the imaginary part
    }
}

// Function to initialize ADC
void ADC_init(void) {
    DDRA = 0x00;
    ADCSRA |= (1 << ADEN) | (1 << ADPS2) | (1 << ADPS1) | (1 << ADPS0);
    ADMUX |= (1 << REFS0);
}

// Function to read ADC value from a specified channel
uint16_t ADC_read(uint8_t channel) {
    ADMUX = (ADMUX & 0xF8) | (channel & 0x07);
    ADCSRA |= (1 << ADSC);
    while (!(ADCSRA & (1 << ADIF)));
    ADCSRA |= (1 << ADIF);
    _delay_ms(1);
    return ADCW;
}

// Function to convert ADC reading to voltage
double ADC_to_Voltage(uint16_t adcValue) {
    double voltage = (adcValue * 2.0457) - 1305.2;
    return voltage;
}

// Function to convert ADC reading to current
double ADC_to_Current(uint16_t adcValue) {
    double current = (adcValue * 0.056311) - 35.617; 
    return current;
}

// Function to calculate power using DFT
double calculatePower(double voltage[], double current[], int n, double frequency) {
    double voltage_real, voltage_imag;
    double current_real, current_imag;
    dft(voltage_data, n, &voltage_real, &voltage_imag, frequency);
    dft(current_data, n, &current_real, &current_imag, frequency);
    
    // Calculate real power as the product of the real parts of voltage and current
    double real_power = voltage_real * current_real + voltage_imag * current_imag;
    
    return real_power;
}

// Function to send LCD command
void LCD_Command(unsigned char cmnd) {
    LCD_Port = (LCD_Port & 0x0F) | (cmnd & 0xF0);
    LCD_Port &= ~(1 << RS);
    LCD_Port |= (1 << EN);
    _delay_us(1);
    LCD_Port &= ~(1 << EN);
    _delay_us(200);
    LCD_Port = (LCD_Port & 0x0F) | (cmnd << 4);
    LCD_Port |= (1 << EN);
    _delay_us(1);
    LCD_Port &= ~(1 << EN);
    _delay_ms(2);
}

// LCD data writing function
void LCD_Char(unsigned char data) {
    LCD_Port = (LCD_Port & 0x0F) | (data & 0xF0);                 
    LCD_Port |= (1 << RS);                                      
    LCD_Port |= (1 << EN);
    _delay_us(1);
    LCD_Port &= ~(1 << EN);
    _delay_us(200);                                               
    LCD_Port = (LCD_Port & 0x0F) | (data << 4);                  
    LCD_Port |= (1 << EN);
    _delay_us(1);
    LCD_Port &= ~(1 << EN);
    _delay_ms(2);
}

// LCD Initialization function
void LCD_Init (void) {
    LCD_Dir = 0xFF;                                              
    _delay_ms(20);                                               
    LCD_Command(0x02);                                          
    LCD_Command(0x28);                                          
    LCD_Command(0x0C);                                          
    LCD_Command(0x06);                                          
    LCD_Command(0x01);                                          
    _delay_ms(2);
}

// Function to display a string on the LCD
void LCD_String(char *str) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; str[i] != 0; i++) {
        LCD_Char(str[i]);
    }
}

// Function to display a string on the LCD with specified position
void LCD_String_xy(char row, char pos, char *str) {
    if (row == 0 && pos < 16)
        LCD_Command((pos & 0x0F) | 0x80);                      
    else if (row == 1 && pos < 16)
        LCD_Command((pos & 0x0F) | 0xC0);                      
    LCD_String(str);                                        
}

void displayPower(double power_val) {
    char powerStr[16];
    sprintf(powerStr, "Power: %.2f W", power_val);

    // Implement a scrolling mechanism here
    int len = strlen(powerStr);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= len; i++) {
        LCD_Command(0x01); // Clear display screen
        _delay_ms(2);
        LCD_String_xy(0, 0, powerStr + i);
        _delay_ms(500); // Delay for scrolling speed
    }
}


int main(void) {
    LCD_Init();
    ADC_init();
 
    int data_index = 0;     

    while (1) {
        // Read ADC values from voltage and current sensors
        uint16_t voltage_adc = ADC_read(VOLTAGE_SENSOR_CHANNEL);
        uint16_t current_adc = ADC_read(CURRENT_SENSOR_CHANNEL);

        // Convert ADC readings to voltage and current with calibration
        double current = ADC_to_Current(current_adc);
        double voltage = ADC_to_Voltage(voltage_adc);

        // Store the latest voltage and current values in the data arrays
        voltage_data[data_index] = voltage;
        current_data[data_index] = current;

        // Increment the data index (use a circular buffer implementation if needed)
        data_index++;
        if (data_index >= N) {
            data_index = 0; 
        }

        // Calculate power using DFT
        double power = calculatePower(voltage_data, current_data, N, 60.0); 

        // Store the calculated power value
        power_data[data_index] = power;

        // Display real power on LCD and scroll through values
        displayPower(power_data[data_index]);
     
        _delay_ms(1); 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However this does not display the real output.
Can someone help me to figure out where I have gone wrong and to do a Discrete Fourier Transformation and display the real values?

Comment: This is beyond me, but... Don't you need more regularity in your sampling intervals, collect N samples, then perform only one DFT calculation on that batch?

Comment: I think that you don't need DFT, but RMS (search for RMS). But then, beware that not all the tools used to measure power are "true RMS" (search also for this).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". Specifically, this is not a forum. Then come back and [edit] your question, what issue you have to implement the algorithm. If you don't know the algorithm, this is the wrong place to ask, I'm afraid. This is a Q&A site for programming, not for math questions.